# C Pipe communicating write/read function cuts of text

Tags: c, pipe, communication

The write or read function always cut of everything except the first letter. anyone knows why?
I have a father and a child that communicating with pipes.
I checked tha variable before putting it into write and it wasnt cutted of .

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    time_t tm_now;
    struct tm *ptm_now;
    time(&tm_now);
    ptm_now = localtime(&tm_now);

    int chanal_father[2];
    int chanal_child[2];
    pipe(chanal_father);
    pipe(chanal_child);
    char message_child[50];
    char message_father[50];
    char message_return[50];


    if (fork()==0)
    {
        read(chanal_father[0], message_father, strlen(message_father)+1);
        if(strcmp(message_father, "day") == 0) {
            int day = ptm_now->tm_mday;
            int month = (ptm_now->tm_mon)+1;
            int year = (ptm_now->tm_year)-1900;         
            sprintf(message_return, "%2d.%2d.%2d", day, month, year);
        }
        else {
            sprintf(message_return, "unknown function!");
        }

        write(chanal_child[1],message_return, strlen(message_return)+1);
        exit(0);
    }

    write(chanal_father[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);
    read(chanal_child[0], message_child, strlen(message_child)+1);
    printf("%s\n", message_child);
}
```

Comment: strlen(message_father)+1 is probably equal to 1? the string is uninitialized. you are only reading one byte. pipes don't go well with variable length messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use strlen() to get the size of your array, use sizeof(). Rember that read() will read up to 'count' bytes:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Also, for clarity you might want to structure your program as follows:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){

   ...

}else{

   ...

}
```

Comment: The difference is that strlen() will determine the length of a string. A string in C is by definition a null terminated array. Since your array is not initialized, strlen() will return 0 for the length.

Comment: By the way, that else{} block should be there in your code, otherwise that code will be executed by both parent and child.